# Sql pgadmin confused

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

The following query gives me a syntax error:

```
Select 
  traseu_stud.An, 
  traseu_stud.CodSpec 
from 
  traseu_stud 
where 
  NumePren = "Popescu W.T. Vasile" 
  and AnUniv = "2012-2013" 
  inner join studenti on traseu_stud.matricol = studenti.matricol 
  inner join persoane on studenti.idPers = persoane.idPers
```

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "inner"
LINE 3: ...Pren="Popescu W.T. Vasile" and AnUniv="2012-2013" inner join...
                                                             ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 122
```

Comment: we need to see the code of the query

Comment: Consider: What is the authoratative justification you think you have for writing this? What is a way that you can express what you want that looks like examples in your reference & you can apparently find justification for?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use subquery if you want use filter in this way:

```
select * from
   (
      Select traseu_stud.An,traseu_stud.CodSpec,matricol 
      from traseu_stud 
      where NumePren='Popescu W.T. Vasile' and AnUniv='2012-2013'
   ) a
inner join studenti on a.matricol=studenti.matricol 
inner join persoane on studenti.idPers=persoane.idPers
```

otherwise you have to use filter below way

```
 Select traseu_stud.An,traseu_stud.CodSpec from 
 traseu_stud  inner join 
 studenti on traseu_stud.matricol=studenti.matricol inner join persoane on 
 studenti.idPers=persoane.idPers
 where NumePren='Popescu W.T. Vasile' and AnUniv='2012-2013'
```

Answer (score 0):

The `JOIN` go into the from clause.

Additionally: String constants need to be enclose in [single quotes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS), double quotes are for identifiers:

```
Select 
  traseu_stud.An, 
  traseu_stud.CodSpec 
from traseu_stud 
  inner join studenti on traseu_stud.matricol = studenti.matricol 
  inner join persoane on studenti.idPers = persoane.idPers
where NumePren = 'Popescu W.T. Vasile'
  and AnUniv = '2012-2013'
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your help, but I have same errors, I put here the image with tables and what I want to do: What Specialization(Specializare) and in what Study year(AnUniv) it's the Popescu W.T. Vasile in 2012-2013.
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1iV1.jpg